# Массовое удаление файлов, по имени, через терминал. debian

Tags: debian, консоль

сложилась такая ситуация, что в корневом каталоге root, собралась масса файлов:

На сайте есть много функционала связанного с кронами, каждое выполнение оставляет за собой файл, в корневой директории, за несколько лет там собралось свыше пол миллиона файлов, которые нет возможности удалить через ftp. (почему сделано так, и почему не реализован функционал удаления файлов не известно, так как делал не я).

Так как познания с терминалом не велики, а файлы находятся прям в главном каталоге, прошу подсказать, как сделать это безопасно, что бы например найти все файлы только в этом каталоге с именем которое начинается на `notice.` и удалить их, без возможного удаления других файлов или каталогов.

**Система debian**

Буду благодарен вашим рекомендациям.

Comment: Используйте find. Смотреть параметры maxdepth, name и delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find -maxdepth 1 -name "notice.*" -exec rm {} \;
```

- ищем по маске, кавычки не дают башу раскрыть звездочку (либо ее нужно заэкранировать: `-name notice.\*`
- `-maxdepth` ограничивать глубину в один уровень
- команда `rm` в таком виде удаляет только файлы

Команда `rm notice.*` также подходит, но не будет работать на полмилионе файлов. Почему? Баш раскрывает звездочку, превращая в команду `rm notice_1 notice_2 notice_3 ...`. Будет слишком большая команда, которую нельзя выполнить в силу ограничений

Comment: На хабре https://habr.com/ru/post/157613/ пишут, что `find` сначала строит список в памяти, потом удаляет. Хотя статья 2012 года, могло что-то поменяться

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, спасибо за ссылку. И что обращаете внимание на год статьи. Теперь вот что я сделал: `man find`, откуда я узнал что эта команда входит в `findutils`, который я выкачал по ссылке https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/findutils.git/ а затем сделал `git log | grep -i memor -C5`. Там есть два коммита: `adadafb09cd739` и `a29e61b873a3b949de9f` от 20 августа 2011 года: `Reduce memory consumption for large
    directories.  Don't save the whole directory content with
    xsavedir, instead just loop over the results of readdir.`. Опираясь на это, думаю, что уже поправили.

Answer (score 0):

Через терминал переходишь в нужный каталог (видимо, `sudo su - && cd /root`) и вводишь `rm notice*` (или `rm notice.*`, если в вопросе у тебя после notice была точка).

Можешь проверить сначала в другой директории: у меня удалились только нужные файлы. При вводе будь осторожен: неправильная команда может привести к удалению многих нужных файлов.

Посмотреть список файлов к удалению можно через `ls | grep notice*`

PS: говорят, что для полумиллиона файлов команда не выполнится. См. комментарии

Comment: Для полумиллиона файлов так себе совет. Баш их будет день сортировать.

Comment: @AlexeyTen ну в любом случае удаление такого количества файлов -- дело не быстрое. Я как-то на Windows удалял несколько миллионов, заняло порядка часа, если не больше

Comment: @AlexeyTen да и вопрос по консоли. Не факт, что автор знает другие языки, да и написать на них сложней, как и запустить. Хотя на Java наверно быстрей бы удалились файлы. Как понимаю, для автора главное -- надежность, а не время.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, все верно часть файлов удалило, но вот файлы которых больше 300000 тысяч оно отказывается удалять, читал про цикл, что возможно через него, но пока не рисковал, так как в комментариях верно подметили, что скорость по сравнению с надежностью сейчас стоит на втором месте. Спасибо!

Comment: `rm notice*` не будет работать на полмилионе файлов - 100%. Почему? Баш раскрывает звезочку, получая команду `rm notice_1 notice_2 notice_3` и так далее. Будет слишком большая команда, и будет ошибка, есть лимит. Тут только через find